# I2S 3W Class D Amplifier and 2.2“ SPI-Display (ILI9341) - GPIO 18 Problem

Tags: pwm, i2s

I want to connect the Adafruit I2S 3W Class D Amplifier Breakout Board and an 2.2" TFT Display (ILI9341) to a Raspberry Pi Zero.

However, it seems that by default both components use the GPIO 18 (the Amplifier for the bit clock and the display for the backlight).

So I would like to change the connection of one of the components to another PWM-Pin (e.g. GPIO 12).

But i could not find where to change the GPIOs. In all the tutorials I read so far, there is no mentioning where the used GPIOs are defined.

Does anyone know how to change the Pin-Configuration for either one of the components so I can use them both with the Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty obvious:

I just put this in /etc/rc.local:

```
gpio -g mode 12 pwm
gpio -g pwm 12 1024
```

Comment: It may work at the moment but it is likely that you run into trouble in the future. Please take note that using `/etc/rc.local` has limitations due to [Compatibility with SysV](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Incompatibilities/). We have seen many problems here on this site using it. Following the recommendation of the developers from **systemd** you should avoid using it.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.